# EDM power supply confusion

Tags: transistors, mosfet

I found this EDM power supply circuit.

How can the N channel MOSFET turn on when the gate voltage is only 12V and the switched voltage 40V?

Why is the gate circuitry grounded through the spark gap?

[image]

Comment: Well, you found the schematic and you are critiquing it so, why don't you look for a design that works for you. Nobody has any idea about where you found this circuit or what it is truly representing except you and the original author.

Comment: Consider the gate circuitry is floating in relation to the 40V circuit, so it is not being grounded via the spark gap. 12V should be more than adequate to fully turn on the mosfet regardless of the voltage across the drain/source. What leads you to believe it isn’t enough? The circuit could be improved, but it looks like it ‘works’.

Comment: Wouldn't this be considered a high side switch where an nmos needs a gate voltage higher than drain to function?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it does not matter where you found this schematic or who made it. It is good, as much as it is simple.

As far as the M1 transistor goes, your question is basically good, but the answer is also simple. You have to look at this M1 transistor from the three contacts it has (gate, source, drain) Whether it switches on or off depends on the voltage between the gate and the source. The 40VDC circuit is independent, as its "ground" is separate (labeled as "0.") I find this circuit a great basis for adding automation circuitry. If you need more power, you might want to play with more powerful (with higher ratings for voltages, currents) components.

Answer (score 0):

MOSFETs are controlled by gate-source voltage. The gate drive circuit is common to the source, not ground.  For example if the MOSFET turns fully on, pulling source up to +40V, the gate will be at 40 + 12 = 52V with respect to ground.  It's not clear what purpose this circuit is intended for, but the function seems to be a pulsed current limiter.  Note the gate supply voltage and pulse generator must be isolated from circuit ground.